# AWS S3 Static Website isn't serving css files

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3

I've gone through most of the previous related questions and answers that appear similar to mine. Here are some of the things I have tried based on what others have suggested:

1. Made bucket public
2. Clear browser cache
3. I've updated the key and value to match text/css

When I click the website endpoint link inside of S3, the CSS files upload to the browser properly.

But when I go directly to the web address from the browser, the page contains no CSS.
The style.css file is saved to my local cpu. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload CSS file to the S3 bucket and make it public. Although your bucket is public, objects inside the bucket are not. You need to explicitly make them public. Uploading and making your CSS file public in public S3 bucket will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've checked this and it did not resolve the problem. The bucket as well as the objects inside are public. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Assume html and css files are public and in the same public bucket. Here's my entry for style.css file in index.html file.<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />. Both index.html and style.css are public and in same public S3 bucket

Comment: It was the code. Thanks. I've been stuck on this for 2 days.